# How to read this json data from server?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I have problem in reading the json data and also reading the image from the server

```
  {
    "DS": {
        "LST": [
            {
                "OID": 1,
                "OCD": "1",
                "OPE": "AIRCEL",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/aircelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 2,
                "OCD": "3",
                "OPE": "AIRTEL",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/airtelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 4,
                "OCD": "4",
                "OPE": "BSNL",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/bsnlsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 6,
                "OCD": "5",
                "OPE": "DOCOMO",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/docomosm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 7,
                "OCD": "6",
                "OPE": "IDEA",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/ideasm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 8,
                "OCD": "7",
                "OPE": "MTS",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/mtssm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 5,
                "OCD": "8",
                "OPE": "RELAINCE",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/reliancesm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            },
            {
                "OID": 3,
                "OCD": "9",
                "OPE": "VODAFONE",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/vodafonesm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            }
        ]
}
}
```

I have tried the code but its not working

```
    ArrayList<SpinnerMenu> selectedNetwork = new ArrayList<>();
        if(jsonStr != null){
            JSONObject json = null;
            SpinnerMenu spinnerData = new SpinnerMenu();
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Create the root JSONObject from the JSON string.
            JSONObject jsonRootObject = null;
            jsonRootObject = json.optJSONObject("DS");

            //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("LST");

            //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                String iph = null;

                String oid = jsonObject.optString("OID").toString();
                String ocd = jsonObject.optString("OCD").toString();
                String opd = jsonObject.optString("OPE").toString();
                String mil = jsonObject.optString("MIL").toString();
                String mxl = jsonObject.optString("MXL").toString();


                try {
                    iph = jsonObject.getString("IPH").toString();
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                String urldisplay = "http://192/TotalRecharge/"+iph;
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e3) {
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }

                spinnerData.setOid(oid);
                spinnerData.setOcd(ocd);
                spinnerData.setOpd(opd);
                spinnerData.setMil(mil);
                spinnerData.setMix(mxl);
                spinnerData.setImage(mIcon11);

                selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);

            }
```

whats wrong in my code.How to get the json data and save it in a arraylist.In my code when i fetched the json data and saved in a arraylist but it returning null.I don't know how to solve this.Please help me

Comment: You didnt even try to save it in array list..

Comment: ArrayList<SpinnerMenu> selectedNetwork = new ArrayList<>(); is it local variable or instance if it is instance it should work. and if it is local it won't work out side of a method.

Comment: @  ImAtWar  please see my code selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData); selected network is the arraylist

Comment: //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("LST");  use getJsonArray("LST");

Comment: //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("LST"); and check lenght of Array

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variable named json twice. This should not even compile. You want to use variable declared before try block.

Also I would suggest using Log.e instead of printStackTrace (in all catch blocks).

```
JSONObject json = null;
try {
    json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    Log.e("mytag", "Unable to parse json", e1");
}
```

There's another problem with spinnerData object. You need to create new instance for each record. You are creating one and just overriding values inside. Move this line:

```
SpinnerMenu spinnerData = new SpinnerMenu();
```

Into the loop:

```
//Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    SpinnerMenu spinnerData = new SpinnerMenu();
```

Comment: Spinner data objects needs to be within the array loop

Comment: @cricket_007 You are right, that's another problem with the code I didn't see.

Comment: @ cricket_007  will you post your answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi man I see That you are Struggling with bidding each value using JSONObject you can use Jackson is a JSON library for Java it's far better here is a link for you to start with :
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

To sum up what you need to do :
-Create POJO's
-Bind them using JacksonMapper 
Example :
First POJO
is

```
{
                "OID": 1,
                "OCD": "1",
                "OPE": "AIRCEL",
                "IPH": "Images/provider/aircelsm.jpg",
                "MIL": 10,
                "MXL": 10
            }
```

will be

```
public class FirstPojo{
@JsonProperty("OID")
Integer oid;
@JsonProperty("OCD")
String ocd;
@JsonProperty("OPE")
String ope;
@JsonProperty("IPH")
String iph;
@JsonProperty("MIL")
Integer mil;
@JsonProperty("MXL")
Integer mxl;
//Getters and Setters
}
```

Than the second POJO will be a list of First POJO's

```
    public class SecondPojo{
    @JsonProperty("LST")
    private List<FirstPojo> lstList;
//Getters and Setters
}
```

and so on the Third POJO will contain an object of the second POJO with the property name DS
Then you can call your Jackson mapper and get your list using the second class getter 
Like :
let's assume you have or get from a network request  your JSON as a  String

```
String jsonString ="{\"DS\":...... ";


try {

    ThirdPojo thirdPojo = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, ThirdPojo.class);
    List<FirstPojo> list=thirdPojo.getlst.getlstList();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

just take your time and discover the Jackson Library :) good Luck